# Why are integrated USB PD PSUs with powerbank not more common?

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, usb-pd, powerbanks

Looking into the circuits and logic behind USB PD (in particular USB-C PD), I wonder why it is not more often done to combine a wall-plug PSU and a power-bank (battery powered PSU) into one. Would that not save a lot of space and cost? I seems to me that a topology of:

`90-250VAC -> DC -> Buck-converter controlled by battery charge controller -> Battery -> Buck converter controlled by USB PD logic + capacitors`

would be cheaper and smaller than

`90-250VAC -> DC + capacitors -> Buck-converter controlled by USB PD logic + capacitors` + `Buck-converter controlled by battery charger with USB PD logic unit -> Battery -> Buck converter controlled by USB PD logic + capacitors`

and maybe even more efficient in a scenario where it is not mostly used stationary? (It could even skip the battery if it is wall-powered and fully charged)

**Is there any major (electrical design) reason speaking against that?** Why don't we see more of these combined devices?

(Side-thought: would it not also make integration of e.g. MPPTs for solar, car chargers, etc easier? I guess that's not a driving factor for most consumers though...)

**Addition:** As pointed out in the further discussion, I'm talking about rather small power-banks and PSUs here. Let's say a 30-65W PSU and 30~60Wh power-bank. Also the main advantage would of course be for multi-day traveling, not so much commuting and certainly not office/home use.

Comment: What problem would that solve? The reason those do not exist may not be technical, but they may not be economically viable.

Comment: That's exactly what I wonder. As I said, I believe the benefits could be: smaller, lighter, cheaper (those are assumed and what I'm asking about), and easier to handle (I hate having to always handle all the cables and boxes. I would prefer one box with AC input and USB-C output).

Comment: No reason it can't be done but probably not much demand for it.

Comment: Why would you need an MPPT for a car charger?

Comment: @SolarMike, those were two examples of possible separate use-cases: 1. solar panel input (MPPT) 2. 10-36V DC charging (car/truck).

Answer (score 1):

The three main reasons that come to mind (in no particular order) are:

1. cost
2. mass
3. size

Note: for 1) most users have a suitable power adapter already so the money can be concentrated in the output side. 2) adding effectively useless mass to a powerbank which can re-power a smart phone 3 or 4 times is not effective, adding an extra cell for more capacity is a better use of the mass though. 3) the total size is also a limiting factor for many people (not all...) as convenience is part of the decision.

Others may decide that there is a priority order to these, but it always depends on the use each person has.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I understand you arguments for stationary (home/office) use (where the mass and size do not actually matter that much). However, when traveling, many people now carry both a charger and a power-bank around. The two devices together should have more mass, volume, and cost than if you were to combine them in the same housing.

Comment: Ahh,  but when you have a charger for the laptop that also works for the powerbank then your argument fails to fly... having to have a charger for the laptop with a second charger built-in to the powerbank is a waste as I outlined above. And I did not write my answer based on home/office.

Comment: Ah, I misread your reply slightly indeed. Sorry! But if I understand correctly this time, this only holds if you already have a sufficiently good power supply (which I think many people still do not, I just purchased a new one the other day) and/or for short trips (where you only carry either a PSU or power-bank). To the "charger for the laptop with a second charger built-in to the powerbank": yes, you need one AC to battery and one DC battery to USB-C PD converter. However, as I outlined in my original question, I think you need more components when you have a separate power-brick and -bank.

Comment: Less components as I only need one power brick for 2 things whereas you suggest 1 built-in to the powerbank and a second for the laptop.

Comment: Ah, is our misunderstanding stemming from that you assume the power-bank will be unusable for a laptop? My relatively small powerbank (5× 18650 cells) is also able to charge my laptop... Also as USB-PD allows constant re-negotiation of deliverable power, the same device could deliver 100W (20V@5A) or 60W (20V@3A) in AC mode and e.g. up to 45W (15V@3A) in battery-powered mode. 45W is still enough for most laptops.

Comment: Ahh, so for those that have cheap / low power laptops but some of us need 85W power supplies as we need the power and capacity.

Comment: As for a powerbank, the best one I can use runs a 2000W inverter for 6 hours.

Comment: Hahaha, fair. I think most people are ok with a 30-65W PSU and 30~60Wh power-bank.